# Load external page into div after clicking on item from php list

Tags: php, ajax, phplist

I know, I know. From the title up above, you are probably wondering what in in the world I am asking. Let me try and break this down a little easier because I am stuck and cannot figure this out. So here goes..............

I have a place on my site where a user can look at a list of news items that have been posted. All of the news items are listed in a MYSQL database and is retrieved and displayed on the page using PhP, like this:

```
$sql_list = "SELECT * FROM LatestMusic WHERE active = 'y' ORDER BY lm_id DESC";  
 $sql_list_result = mysql_query($sql_list,$connection) or die ('Could not select the List of Latest Music Entries');  

 $bgc = "FFC6C6";  
while($list_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_list_result)){  
    if ($bgc == "FFC6C6") {  
        $bgc = "FFFFFF";  
    } else {  
        $bgc = "FFC6C6";  
    }  
print "<tr bgcolor=\"#" .$bgc. "\">";  
print "<td align=\"center\" width=\"44\">";  
print "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"loadXMLDoc()\"><img src=\"/images/b_edit.png\" border=\"0\"></a>";  
print "</td>";  
print "<td align=\"center\" width=\"63\">";  
print "<img src=\"/images/b_drop.png\" border=\"0\">";  
print "</td>";  
print "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left: 15px;\">";  
echo $list_data[1];  
print "</td>";  
print "</tr>";  
}
```

That part I get. From there, when the user click on anyone of the entries listed from the database, I need an external PHP page to load inside of a DIV on the same page without loading. I am using this coding in the header on the same page in order to achieve such a task:

```
<script>  
 function loadXMLDoc() {
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else { // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "YSMhome_LMeditform.php", true);
     xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

I can get the external page to load just fine into the DIV without the page reloading. The problem I'm having is this: The page that loads needs to be a form with form fields. When a user clicks on an entry in the list from the database, I need to pass a variable from the list (letting me know which entry they clicked on) into the external page that is loading in the DIV so that I can pre-populate the form fields with the data being sent. That is the part I cannot figure out.

If anyone can assist me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I am new to AJAX (this is my first attempt with it), but I am willing to learn what I need to in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your ajax function, you need to pass it the relevant information. In your example, you should change:

```
onclick=\"loadXMLDoc()\"
```

to something like (assuming that `$list_data[0]` is an integer for simplicity):

```
onclick=\"loadXMLDoc({$list_data[0]})\"
```

Then in javascript, your function definition would look something like:

```
function loadXMLDoc(id)
```

and later on, you could change the url that is called to something like:

```
"YSMhome_LMeditform.php?id=" + id
```

Then you would have the ID available in `"YSMhome_LMeditform.php` as `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @jeroen. I made all the changes (and it all makes sense to me as well.....which is weird....LOL) but I am still not getting the id variable to pass to the external page that is loading. My guess, which might not account for much, would be that the problem is somewhere in the: "YSMhome_LMeditform.php?id=" + id.  This is just a guess on my part, but I can feel that we are soooo close to getting this to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2574777 Can you confirm the value of `id` right before you make the request?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but seeing as I am new to this stuff, how would I be able to confirm the value of id? One thing I was able to do when I tried it online and it didn't work, is I viewed the source code and I could see that the value is being passed from the php code into the function. That I do know is working, I'm just not sure how to confirm what's happening to that value inside of the function. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2574777 You could do a `console.log(id)` right before you make the request and check in the console what the value is.

Comment: One more stupid question if you don't mind: How do I check the console? I use IE, but I can check it in Firefox if you need me to. Thanks, and sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Hey!! Good news!! It's working. You're coding suggestion did the trick. I'm not sure why it decided to all of a sudden start working, but it is and that's all that matters. :) Thanks so much for all the help with this. You were a BIG help.